# Three.js post-processing: How to keep depth texture for multiple passes?

Tags: three.js, shader, depth-buffer

I am rendering a scene using three.js that needs multiple post-processing passes. Most of those steps need the depth buffer. My plan was to first render all visible objects to obtain the color and depth and then render all post-processing passes using 2 framebuffers which are alternating read and write framebuffers. The passes are just examples:

1. Render Objects -> FB0
2. DistortionPass, taking FB0 as input -> FB1
3. GodrayPass, taking FB1 as input -> FB0
4. SSAOPass, taking FB0 as input -> screen

The GodrayPass needs to read the depth of the first render pass, therefore I need to bind the depth texture and it should not be the one bound to FB0, otherwise it would lead to a feedback loop, since that shader is writing to FB0.

I think it would make sense to copy the depth into a separate texture after rendering the objects, so I can bind this texture whenever needed in a pass without worrying about a feedback loop.

However,

- copyTexImage2D seem to not support copying from the depth buffer.
- using a shader to pack the depth buffer after the first pass into an RGBA8 texture would require every pass to "unpack" the float again
- render all objects again using a shader that output the depth to the color buffer? Would require packing or precision loss again.

What is the best practice here? Am I on the right path?

I can make use of WebGL 2.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0), but would like to avoid using unpopular extensions.

Comment: which are you using, Three.js or WebGL? They are not the same, require people with entirely different knowledge to answer, and the answers will be totally different

Comment: I am using Three.js utilizing the WebGL renderer, however I am willed to modify three.js if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three.js doesn't call them FB's, it calls them `RenderTarget`s. For webgl they are `WebGLRenderTarget`

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget

[This example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_depth_texture.html) show setting up a depth texture with a render target

```
target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
target.texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
target.texture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
target.texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
target.texture.generateMipmaps = false;
target.stencilBuffer = false;
target.depthBuffer = true;
target.depthTexture = new THREE.DepthTexture();
target.depthTexture.format = THREE.DepthFormat;
target.depthTexture.type = THREE.UnsignedShortType;
```

And [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-rendertargets.html) shows rendering to render targets. And [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing.html) shows rendering to render targets for the purposes of post processing using `EffectComposer` and `Pass` three.js objects.

So, just make 3 render targets

```
RT0 = color + depth
RT1 = color
RT2 = color
```

Then setup `Pass` objects such that

```
Render Objects -> RT0(color+depth)
DistortionPass, taking RT0(color) as input -> RT1(color)
GodrayPass, taking RT1(color) + RT0(depth) as input -> RT2(color)
SSAOPass, taking RT2(color as input -> screen
```